# AES-NI enable or disable

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes-ni

I measured the performance of `AES` using following command before and after setting the kernel config `CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL` but the performance is very similar, i am not sure is it using `AES-NI` or not, i check the cpu is `AES-NI` capable and `CPUID` shows `AES-NI` enable,

```
# openssl s_time -connect myserver:443 -www /file.html -new -time 30 -cipher AES128-SHA
Collecting connection statistics for 30 seconds
2293 connections in 10.42s; 220.06 connections/user sec, bytes read
2404343494
2293 connections in 31 real seconds, 1048558 bytes read per connection
```

why enabling the config option `CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL` doesn't make any difference. please note i already had the

```
CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_X86_64=y 
CONFIG_CRYPTO_CRYPTD=y
```

in both the case

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 4):

CPU's are simply *very fast* so you may indeed not notice much. In general native code will be so fast that it simply saturates the connection, leaving only the actual I/O timing and latency / encryption overhead (the SSL frames will still result in more bytes having to be send). Furthermore, the [HMAC (a *hash based* message authentication code) over the plaintext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Data_integrity) will take about as much time as the encryption itself.

You may actually have about twice the performance compared to CPU only encryption *for the AES calculations themselves*. Of course you'd still be missing the enhanced protection against timing attacks, the fact that the ALU's don't get hammered and possibly some power advantages if you disable AES-NI.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
-evp
```

and change cipher

Hope it helps.